# Switching between two reports with parameter based on parameter selection

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have two SSRS reports both having their own set of parameters with them. I want to switch between the two. The problem is that I can switch the reports based on a boolean parameter if the reports are not having parameters but both reports have different parameters. What are the possible ways that I can achieve this?

Comment: Can't think of an easy way out of the box. You'll likely need to design a webpage that handles this yourself.

Comment: are the returned datasets the same?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about linked report (with the checkbox "go to report") when you create a report ?

Maybe there is another way more efficient but the first idea I have is to create the same parameters in both report (report1's param + report2's param) then you can pass from a report to the other one with all of the parameters.